# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. Unsure What This is?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, vb.net

I'm building a website, and I am trying to create a connection to the database. Here is the Connection code in my web.config file:

```
<add name="DBX" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;User Id=USER;Password=PASSWORD" providerName="SqlDataSource" />
```

And this is the code I'm using in the code behind page:

```
Protected Conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("DBX")
```

When I go to view the web page, I get the following error:

> Format of the initialization string
>   does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 0.

And this highlights the Connection string in the VB.NET code behind page. I've checked the details of the original connection string contained within the web.config file, and I've used the ConnectionStrings.com website for the actual code. I'm at a loss to explain or to figure out why this isn't working?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"DBX"` is not the correct format for a ConnectionString ;-)

What you really wanted is the [ConnectionString section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx) of your DBX-Connection in the web.config:

```
Protected Conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBX").ConnectionString)
```

Comment: Oh right, I thought you could call that anything, hence why I named it DBX. I will try this out tomorrow and let you know. Cheers! :)

Comment: There is no magic web.config-lookup in the constructor of a SqlConnection. Glad i could help.

Comment: Hey, I've just managed to try what you've said but I still get the error?

Comment: What have you tried and what error do you get exactly? Edit your question accordingly please, then we can have a look.